# Magento - Block provided by custom extension is not loaded

Tags: magento, layout, module, php

I've finally reached the "rendering" phase of my second Magento module, but I'm stuck again. The module is now almost complete, it has a Controller and two blocks, one of which is called by the first (one is a dashboard block, which uses the second one to populate sub-sections).

What I need to do now it add this new dashboard to Customer Account Dashboard. I was told to use layout files, and I've read about them on Magento Design Guide. I then created the layout file and added the declaration of my block in it. However, the dashboard is not modified and my data is not displayed. If I call the extension method manually (i.e. myserver/customerstats/index) I get back the snippet of HTML that I'd like to display on Customer Account page.

At first I thought that my layout file was not loaded, but I now have the proof that it's processed correctly (at least, part of it). Here's the layout file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_index translate="label">
        <label>My Custom Dashboard</label>
        <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
            <!-- The action is processed correctly, the template is overridden -->
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>customerstats/customer/account/dashboard.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="customerstats/index" name="customerstats_dashboard" as="customerstats.dashboard" template="customerstats/customerstatsdashboard.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_index>
</layout>
```

I added the setTemplate action to the layout file because one of the requirements is that the new dashboard is split in two parts vertically. This means I had to modify the original *customer/account/dashboard.phtml* and change the structure of the page, adding two  sections that will be styled as required. I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing it, but I couldn't figure out how to add my additional  in a specific part of the page, without touching the .phtml file.

I modified the new *dashboard.phtml*, to make sure it was loaded, and I can see the Customer Account page showing my changes when I enable the action. However, the block that should be rendered by my extension doesn't appear on the page and, based on my simple "trap" (a simple "die()", to prove the code is executed), the extension method doesn't even seem to be called.

Here's the Controller I'm trying to call from the block, with the irrelevant parts removed.

```
class MyCompany_CustomerStats_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    // The loaded block is setting its own template in the _construct() phase
    $Block = &$this->getLayout()->createBlock('customerstats/customerstatsdashboard');

    // Some data is loaded elsewhere and passed to the Block

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $Block->toHtml()
    );
}
```

The Controller is fired properly if I call it manually (myserver
/customerstats/index) and it returns fully rendered HTML, but, as mentioned in the beginning, it doesn't seem to run when the layout file comes into play.

To summarize, here are my questions:
 - Am I on the right track regarding the override of Customer Account Dashboard?
 - Do I have to specify a *template* attribute in the layout for the extension? All the blocks I implemented load their template via code (there's a logic for choosing which one to use), and I don't see the use in having the template indicated in the xml file as well.
 - Once I add a block to the XML file, do I have to alter the dashboard.phtml file to render it somewhere? I'm asking because I saw the original dashboard template, and it contains various calls to `getChildHtml('alias name of a block')`. This leads me to think that blocks don't have to just be "exposed" in the layout file, but also manually called in the .phtml files. However, this is a speculation, since I don't have a clear understanding of the mechanism. **Note**: I also tried to call `getChildHtml('customerstats.dashboard)` inside my new dashboard.phtml, but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

**Update 1 - 2012/07/28**
This is the code for the Block that is not rendered.

```
class MyCompany_CustomerStats_Block_UserStatsDashboard extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    const _TEMPLATE = 'customerStats/userstatsdashboard.phtml';

    public function _construct() {
        $this->setTemplate(self::_TEMPLATE);
    }
}
```

Also, I made an experiment with the Controller itself. I changed it as follows:

```
class MyCompany_CustomerStats_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    die('Controller called successfully.');
}
```

Here are the results:
- If I call "myserver/customerstats/index" from the browser, I get the message "Controller called successfully.".
- If I load the dashboard page which I modified, I can see the new layout (which means that my dashboard is loaded), but not the message. To me, this means that the Controller didn't even get called.

Content of **Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_CustomerStats>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_CustomerStats>
    </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <CustomerStats>
        <class>MyCompany_CustomerStats_Helper</class>
      </CustomerStats>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <CustomerStats>
        <class>MyCompany_CustomerStats_Model</class>
      </CustomerStats>
    </models>
    <blocks>
      <CustomerStats>
        <class>MyCompany_CustomerStats_Block</class>
      </CustomerStats>
    </blocks>
  </global>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <CustomerStats>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>MyCompany_CustomerStats</module>
          <frontName>userstats</frontName>
        </args>
      </CustomerStats>
    </routers>
        <layout>
        <updates>
          <CustomerStats>
                  <file>customerstats.xml</file>
                </CustomerStats>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

**Update 2 - 2012/07/28**
I made an experiment that, I admit, makes absolutely no sense to me from an MVC perspective. I changed the layout and specified block type as *customerstats/userstatsdashboard*. I then modified the Block class `MyCompany_CustomerStats_Block_UserStatsDashboard` as follows:

```
public function _construct() {
    echo "Block rendered.";
}
```

Surprisingly, now something appears in the new layout, exactly where I would expect it! But this means that the Controller hasn't been called at all, which, in turn, means there's no data available for the blocks.
This really perplexes me, I've never seen an MVC model where Views manage themselves... What's the purpose of the extension's controller, then?

Comment: A quick suggestion, try changing reference_name to = "content"

Comment: Thanks paperids, but may I ask you why? The reference should be the block I want to "interact" with, and the block is "customer_account_dashboard". In fact, as I wrote, its template is changed as I expect. It's just my content that is not appended to it, for somewhat reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block class group is `CustomerStats`, but you are not using this in your layout. Block class groups are simply unique text nodes under `global/blocks` and *in no way* need to "match" any folder structure (FYI). This string matters only in that it matches the first part (before the slash) of any call to `createBlock()`, meaning that your layout XML should specify e.g. `type="CustomerStats/whatever"`

In the above example the classname which would be generated would be `MyCompany_CustomerStats_Block_Whatever` based on your class prefix of `MyCompany_CustomerStats_Block`.

Comment: Thanks benmarks. One thing is not clear to me: what I need to do is to populate a template with some HTML which, in turn, is produced by a call to the Controller method "MyCompany_CustomerStats_IndexController". This Controller will then load a block, which will use some data and produce HTML. Therefore, the call should be done to a Controller, not directly to a Block.

Comment: Also, `createBlock()` is called inside the controller, who is preparing the data, loading the correct block class and return the HTML. In short, I'm not sure how much of the block attributes specified in the layout is actually needed in my case. Neither the Controller nor the Blocks take it into account. In fact, the extension works perfectly without the layout file, the only issue I'm having is embedding the result of the rendering in a template.

Comment: Correct. Like most MVC frameworks, the Magento MVC architecture has the action controllers modify the response object. This is done either directly, through deliberate block rendering, or via rendering through the layout XML view modeling. Where Magento deviates a bit is to have the view (blocks) load their own data, conventionally done in the `_prepareLayout()` method. Stated another way: Magento controllers *generally* do not load or deal with any data which is not needed for (re)directing requests.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm following. I know about `_prepareLayout()` because I used it (I have a main block which will load several sub-blocks to render subsections), but the main block is given the data by the Controller. In short, if I were to load the block itself, skipping the controller entirely, I would end up with an empty HTML structure, as the block has no data to render.

Comment: I understand your misunderstanding :-). Ground rules: You should (must) use an action controller to respond to the user request. In the controller action, it is up to you to decide how to modify the request object. It would be difficult (and inappropriate) to route a request to a block class instance. FWIW the request flow is: `Mage::run()` > `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()` > `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()` > `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match()` > `Controller::action()` > `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http::sendResponse()`.

Comment: Thanks again benmarks. I updated my question with an experiment I made, but it just raised more questions.  First of all, I'd expect the Controller to be the one in charge of pulling the strings, and the Block to simply take what it's given and do some rendering. Second, if the Block is the one who "manages itself", and the Controller doesn't even get called when the block is embedded in another page, why do I even need a Controller? My extension won't be handling customer requests, all the output will be rendered inside another page. Does it mean I can get rid of the indexAction altogether?

Comment: And also, you wrote * It would be difficult (and inappropriate) to route a request to a block class instance*. However, I'm understanding that `indexAction()` is not where the "strings are pulled", as Blocks, from what I read, should load Models and apply business logic by themselves (which is against MVC principles, in my opinion). However, if such is the case, what should the Controller do? Not load the data, not apply logic but also not "just pass the Request". What else is left?

Comment: I just found something interesting, which confirms what you wrote: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento/. It says "Block classes are almost like little mini-controllers", which is what I didn't understand in the first place. Unfortunately, having a Controller which doesn't really behave as such, and Blocks that do act as Controllers is not the most intuitive mechanism. Adding my lack of training on Magento (it was a "dive into the job") didn't help either. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without taking the exceptions into account, there are two types of blocks. A `core/text_list` and all other types. When referencing to a `core/text_list`, for example the `content` block all added blocks are automatically rendered.

When referencing to something different than `core/text_list`, in your case `customer/account_dashboard` you need to fetch the content yourself from within the template. This can be done, like you already suggested yourself, via a `getChildHtml()` call.

What might be wrong, though I can't verify this with the code you provided so far, is that your own `customerstats/index` block type can't be found in your module or it's not extending `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Or you're passing a non-existing classgroup into the createBlock factory method.

So within your module there should be something like:

```
    <blocks>
        <customerstats>
            <class><your_namespace>_Customerstats_Block</class>
        </customerstats>
    </blocks>
```

But I think you might have a handle there called `customerdata` instead of `customerstats`.
Since the block you call from the controller is of type `customerdata/customerstatsdashboard` and that one works. Though the one in your XML which uses `customerstats`. If this is the case you might want to try and adjust your XML to:

```
<block type="customerdata/index" name="customerstats_dashboard" as="customerstats.dashboard" template="customerdata/customerstatsdashboard.phtml" />
```

Furthermore when working with templates your block should look like. Thus always extending the Mage_Core_Block_Template. Otherwise `getChildHtml` will not be available. `<your_namespace>_Customerstats_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`

Hopefully this helps you with your task, otherwise please provide feedback after you've tried this.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The block that doesn't render extends Mage_Core_Block_Template and both the createBlock() and getChildHtml() work if I run them "manually", i.e. not through the layout xml file. I amended the files as you suggested (please see the modified question), but the block is still not loaded.

Comment: Could you also include your config.xml of the module please?

Comment: I have another question, about something you wrote: "When referencing to something different than `core/text_list` you need to fetch the content yourself from within the template". So, if I got it right, if I want to add my content to any block which is not a `core/text_list` I have to provide also my own .phtml file. In my case, such template file will be an almost identical copy of the original one, plus the extra call to my own `getChildHtml()`. If that's right, what happens if two or more modules want to add content to the same block? Won't they stomp on each other's "template toes"?

Comment: When you append a child block to a parent, via a reference, the template of the parent block stays the same. You only provide a template for the child block you are adding. Each subblock has its own template, they never, at least in your case, overlap.

For every subblock you add you will need to do a `getChildHtml()` in the template of the parent block.

Comment: Thanks Tim. However, the parent block's template is part of the theme, that I'm not going to change. Therefore, to alter the template and add the call to my block, I took the parent's template and replaced it with mine. My doubt about overlapping was raised by this approach, because my modified .phtml is required by my extension, while another module may require the same .phtml to be different.

Comment: Also, not only my block goes inside another block (not just appended after), but the container block's layout had to be modified as well, to contain the new data.